# Next.js Client Component Error - async/await not supported despite not using async/await

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am encountering an issue in a Next.js client component where I receive the following error after a setTimeout reaches its 5000ms delay:

`Unhandled Runtime Error Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server.`

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
"use client";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import SanityLink from "./SanityLink";
import { X } from "lucide-react";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

type MarketingPopupProps = {
  data: {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    buttonText: string;
    buttonLink: {
      external: string;
    };
    visible: string;
  };
};

function MarketingPopup({ data }: MarketingPopupProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsOpen(true);
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [setIsOpen]);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  if (!data || data.visible !== "yes" || !isOpen) {
    return null;
  }

  const { title, description, buttonText, buttonLink } = data;

  return (
    <div
      className={cn(
        "w-full h-full bg-black bg-opacity-70 flex justify-center items-center z-50",
        isOpen ? "fixed top-0 left-0" : "hidden"
      )}
    >
      <div className="relative">
        <Button
          variant={"ghost"}
          className="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:bg-transparent absolute top-0 right-0"
          onClick={handleClose}
        >
          <X className="w-5 h-5" />
        </Button>
        <div className="bg-white p-8 rounded-lg max-w-md text-center">
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">{title}</h2>
          <p className="text-gray-700 mb-6">{description}</p>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>
            <SanityLink href={buttonLink}>{buttonText}</SanityLink>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MarketingPopup;
```

I'm not using async/await explicitly in my code, and I'm confused about why this error is occurring in a client component. Can anyone provide insights into why this error might be happening and suggest a solution or workaround?